Need help with angles in Tikz picture
The following tikz picture generates two angled lines which, in principle, should have the same angle, but when I compile the code I get two lines with different angles. The lines wich I am refering to are at the bottom of the code. How can I fix this?

\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Línea vertical correspondiente a la fuente de luz
\draw[line width=1mm] (0,0) -- (0,8);
% Efecto de línea que continúa
\draw[dashed, line width=0.5mm] (0,0) -- (0,-1);
% Texto debajo de fuente de luz
\node at (0,-1.5) {Fuente de luz};

% Línea vertical correspondiente con el espejo fijo M_1
\draw[ultra thick] (6,0) -- (6,8);
% Efecto de línea que continúa
\draw[dashed, line width=0.5mm] (6,0) -- (6,-1);
% Texto debajo de la línea gruesa
\node at (6,-1.5) {$\mathrm{M_1}$};
\node at (6, -2) {Espejo fijo};

% Línea vertical correspondiente con el espejo móvil M_2
\draw[ultra thick] (10,0) -- (10,8);
% Efecto de línea que continúa
\draw[dashed, line width=0.5mm] (10,0) -- (10,-1);
% Texto debajo de la línea gruesa
\node at (10,-1.5) {$\mathrm{M_2}$};
\node at (10, -2) {Espejo móvil};

% Dibuja una línea con una flecha en cada extremo
\draw[<->, thick] (6,7.5) -- (10,7.5);
%Texto para la separación espejos
\node at (8, 7.75) {$d$};

% Custom dashed line
\draw[dash pattern=on 8pt off 5pt] (-1,2) -- (11,2);
%Texto
\node at (12.5,2.25) {Eje central};
\node at (12.5,1.75) {del interferómetro};

%Dibujar el rayo de luz
% Dibuja la línea con ángulo
\draw[thick] (0,2) -- (30:6.93cm); % 30 grados y 5 cm de longitud

% Dibuja la línea con ángulo
\draw[thick] (0,2) -- (30:11.55cm); % 30 grados y 5 cm de longitud
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Thank you in advance.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

May be you forgot to add a + before the 2nd coordinates? As it is now you specify them in absolute polar coordinates. With the + they‘d start lines at (0,2) and head off at 30deg from there. // BTW, you‘ll see just 1 line, as one draws over the other …

I have just made a MWE by adding \documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone} \begin{document} ... \end{document}  to the OP's code

I guess you want to specify relative coordinates. As said by Mico, you need to use + before the coordinate for that:
\draw[thick] (0,2) -- +(30:6.93cm);
\draw[thick] (0,2) -- +(30:11.55cm);

Full example:
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Línea vertical correspondiente a la fuente de luz
\draw[line width=1mm] (0,0) -- (0,8);
% Efecto de línea que continúa
\draw[dashed, line width=0.5mm] (0,0) -- (0,-1);
% Texto debajo de fuente de luz
\node at (0,-1.5) {Fuente de luz};

% Línea vertical correspondiente con el espejo fijo M_1
\draw[ultra thick] (6,0) -- (6,8);
% Efecto de línea que continúa
\draw[dashed, line width=0.5mm] (6,0) -- (6,-1);
% Texto debajo de la línea gruesa
\node at (6,-1.5) {$\mathrm{M_1}$};
\node at (6, -2) {Espejo fijo};

% Línea vertical correspondiente con el espejo móvil M_2
\draw[ultra thick] (10,0) -- (10,8);
% Efecto de línea que continúa
\draw[dashed, line width=0.5mm] (10,0) -- (10,-1);
% Texto debajo de la línea gruesa
\node at (10,-1.5) {$\mathrm{M_2}$};
\node at (10, -2) {Espejo móvil};

% Dibuja una línea con una flecha en cada extremo
\draw[<->, thick] (6,7.5) -- (10,7.5);
%Texto para la separación espejos
\node at (8, 7.75) {$d$};

% Custom dashed line
\draw[dash pattern=on 8pt off 5pt] (-1,2) -- (11,2);
%Texto
\node at (12.5,2.25) {Eje central};
\node at (12.5,1.75) {del interferómetro};

%Dibujar el rayo de luz
% Dibuja la línea con ángulo
\draw[thick] (0,2) -- +(30:6.93cm); % 30 grados y 5 cm de longitud

% Dibuja la línea con ángulo
\draw[thick] (0,2) -- +(30:11.55cm); % 30 grados y 5 cm de longitud
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


